# Erlang Dynamic supervisor start gen_server

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I have root supervisor that create other supervisor:

```
start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).

init([]) ->
    RestartStrategy = {one_for_one, 5, 600},
    ListenerSup =
            {popd_listener_sup,
            {popd_listener_sup, start_link, []},
             permanent, 2000, supervisor, [popd_listener]},

    Children = [ListenerSup],

    {ok, {RestartStrategy, Children}}.
```

And i have gen_server - listener. How can i run this gen_server with `popd_listener_sup` supervisor, when supervisor created?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Root supervisor

```
-module(root_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).
-export([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1, shutdown/0]).

start_link() ->
     supervisor:start_link({local,?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).

init(_Args) ->
     RestartStrategy = {one_for_one, 10, 60},
     ListenerSup = {popd_listener_sup,
          {popd_listener_sup, start_link, []},
          permanent, infinity, supervisor, [popd_listener_sup]},
     Children = [ListenerSup],
     {ok, {RestartStrategy, Children}}.    

% supervisor can be shutdown by calling exit(SupPid,shutdown)
% or, if it's linked to its parent, by parent calling exit/1.
shutdown() ->
     exit(whereis(?MODULE), shutdown).
     % or
     % exit(normal).
```

If the child process is another supervisor, `Shutdown` in child specification should be set to `infinity` to give the subtree ample time to shutdown, and `Type` should be set to `supervisor`, and that's what we did.

### Child supervisor

```
-module(popd_listener_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).
-export([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1]).

start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local,?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).

init(_Args) ->
    RestartStrategy = {one_for_one, 10, 60},
    Listener = {ch1, {ch1, start_link, []},
            permanent, 2000, worker, [ch1]},
    Children = [Listener],
    {ok, {RestartStrategy, Children}}.
```

Here, in a child specification, we set value of `Shutdown` to `2000`. An integer timeout value means that the supervisor will tell the child process to terminate by calling `exit(Child,shutdown)` and then wait for an exit signal with reason shutdown back from the child process.

### Listener

```
-module(ch1).
-behaviour(gen_server).

% Callback functions which should be exported
-export([init/1]).
-export([handle_cast/2, terminate/2]).

% user-defined interface functions
-export([start_link/0]).

start_link() ->
     gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

init(_Args) ->
     erlang:process_flag(trap_exit, true),
     io:format("ch1 has started (~w)~n", [self()]),
     % If the initialization is successful, the function
     % should return {ok,State}, {ok,State,Timeout} ..
     {ok, []}.

handle_cast(calc, State) ->
     io:format("result 2+2=4~n"),
     {noreply, State};
handle_cast(calcbad, State) ->
     io:format("result 1/0~n"),
     1 / 0,
     {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
     io:format("ch1: terminating.~n"),
     ok.
```

From Erlang/OTP documentation:

> If the gen_server is part of a
>   supervision tree and is ordered by its
>   supervisor to terminate, the function
>   `Module:terminate(Reason, State)` will
>   be called with `Reason=shutdown` if
>   the following conditions apply:
>
> - the `gen_server` has been set to trap exit signals, and
> - the shutdown strategy as defined in the supervisor's child specification
>     is an integer timeout value, not
>     brutal_kill.

That's why we called `erlang:process_flag(trap_exit, true)` in `Module:init(Args)`.

### Sample run

Starting the root supervisor:

```
1> root_sup:start_link().
ch1 has started (<0.35.0>)
{ok,<0.33.0>}
```

Root supervisor is run and automatically starts its child processes, child supervisor in our case. Child supervisor in turn starts its child processes; we have only one child in our case, `ch1`.

Let's make `ch1` evaluate normal code:

```
2> gen_server:cast(ch1, calc).
result 2+2=4
ok
```

Now some bad code:

```
3> gen_server:cast(ch1, calcbad).
result 1/0
ok
ch1: terminating.

=ERROR REPORT==== 31-Jan-2011::01:38:44 ===
** Generic server ch1 terminating 
** Last message in was {'$gen_cast',calcbad}
** When Server state == []
** Reason for termination == 
** {badarith,[{ch1,handle_cast,2},
              {gen_server,handle_msg,5},
              {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}
ch1 has started (<0.39.0>)
4> exit(normal).
ch1: terminating.
** exception exit: normal
```

As you may see child process `ch1` was restarted by the child supervisor `popd_listener_sup` (notice `ch1 has started (<0.39.0>)`).

Since our shell and root supervisor are bidirectionally linked (call `supervisor:start_link`, not `supervisor:start` in the root supervisor function `start_link/0`), `exit(normal)` resulted in the root supervisor shutdown, but its child processes had some time to clean up.